# how do I change ID of an element dynamically in polymer?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a template including dom-repeat in it.
For repeated every items I need to change ID.
How can I do it with simple way.
And I am using this ID's in document.querySelector to get element.

```
       onCount: function () {
       var child = document.querySelector("#child");
       var adult = document.querySelector("#adult")
       }
```

I am using ID's something like this.

And I want ID's like childR1, childR2,......

Answer (score 3):

Use `$=` to bind attributes.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}" index-as="index">
    <div id$="{{getId(index)}}"></div>
</template>
.
.
getId: function(index) {
  return "childR"+index;
}
```

You can read about it [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#anatomy-of-a-data-binding)

> To bind to an attribute instead, use the attribute name followed by $: